# cPanel - Have unique forwarding address

Tags: email

I am trying to configure a mail everyone@example.com and configure it so that when, lets say, john@example.com sends a mail to everyone@example.com it gets to sarah@ jane@ and tom@ (sorry for the lame examples!)

This mail has to get to all the "list" **with the FROM from everyone@example.com** so that they can just reply there and everybody else will get it.

None of the main "bulk email" providers (phplist etc) seems to be configurable that way.

I´m open to suggestions and I hope I´m explaining myself, if not please ask for clarifications!

**EDIT:**

I agree with Kyle Brants´ comment this could be done with mailing list (in cPanel) MAILMAN but I still have no idea how to configure it!

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with cpanel in particular, but what you are looking for is generally referred to as a "Mailing list".

Comment: Okay, so `sender@example.com` sends a message to `everyone@yourdomain.com` and you want the message to be sent to a list of e-mails `@yourdomain.com` with a reply-to address of the sender and a CC address of `everyone@yourdomain.com` right?

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a mailing list program, like phpList using cPanel.

Go to Fantastico De Luxe and choose phpList.

Here are HostGator's instructions: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/e-mail/how-to-set-up-a-mailing-list-in-cpanel .

Comment: Hi, I wrote in my question "None of the main "bulk email" providers (phplist etc) seems to be configurable that way." Maybe I don´t know how to configure them but that is what I need! Thanks you very much

Comment: Ok, here's some info about how to install mailman on cpanel http://wiki.list.org/display/DOC/Mailman+and+CPanel. Specifically they suggest this joomla extension http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/2409/details . I think the joomla extension might be an easy way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This [SiteGround cPanel E-mail Forwarder Tutorial](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/email/email_forwarding.htm) should explain everything you need to get a forwarder set up.

**10/20 Edit:** Writing a bash script to accomplish this task seemed like it would be fun (at first, anyway) but the lack of MIME multipart support in `formail` makes it ugly.

I might give a PHP script a try at a later date, but the suggestion to use a prepackaged solution makes more sense than trying to roll one's own.

**10/21 Edit:** I took this one as a kind of challenge so here (without any guarantee of support/working code) is what I came up with - I still recommend using an existing solution **over** using this script, but I couldn't resist scripting a proof-of-concept.

I got it working with a cPanel installation but I haven't bothered w/MIME support so attachments and HTML e-mail will be stripped and only plaintext will get delivered.

1. Save the script (below) to a file and update to match your cPanel configuration
2. Upload the file to `/home/example/mail-everyone.php` (or similar) and follow the pipe-to-script setup guide (Address to Forward: "everyone", Pipe to program: "mail-everyone.php")
3. Send a few test messages - you should see the message hit your `NOTIFY_EMAIL` account with a debugging e-mail (until `FLAG_DEBUG` is set to false) and all other cPanel-enabled e-mail addresses should see plaintext BCC copies.

--

```
<?php
define( 'FLAG_DEBUG', true ); // default: true
define( 'FLAG_DEBUG_RAW', false ); // default: false
define( 'NOTIFY_EMAIL', 'you@example.com' );
define( 'CPANEL_DOMAIN', 'example.com' );
define( 'CPANEL_PATH', '/home/example/' );
define( 'CPANEL_PATH_USERS', constant('CPANEL_PATH') . 'etc/' . constant('CPANEL_DOMAIN') . '/quota' );
define( 'EML_SENDER', 'everyone@' . constant('CPANEL_DOMAIN') );
define( 'EML_SUBJECT_PREPEND', '(everyone) ' );
define( 'EML_SUBJECT_APPEND', '' );
define( 'EML_XMAILER', __FILE__.'; PHP/'.phpversion() );
define( 'END_LINE', "\r\n" );

function debugging( $message, $notify = false ) {
    global $debugging;
    if ( defined('FLAG_DEBUG') && constant('FLAG_DEBUG') ) {
        $debugging[] = $message;
    }
    if ( $notify ) {
        $outgoing_headers = array(
            'From' => constant('EML_SENDER'),
            'Reply-To' => constant('NOTIFY_EMAIL'),
            'X-Mailer' => constant('EML_XMAILER')
        );
        $message = implode( constant('END_LINE'), $debugging );
        $flag_sent = send_mail( constant('NOTIFY_EMAIL'), __FILE__.': Debug Notice', $message, $outgoing_headers );
    }
    return;
}
function scan_headers( $search, $target ) {
    $matches = array();
    $pattern = '/^' . strtolower($target) . ':/i';
    if ( preg_match( $pattern, $search ) ) {
        return substr( $search, strlen($target . ': ') );
    }
}
function send_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers_array = false ) {
    if ( is_array($headers_array) ) {
        $header_string = '';
        foreach ( $headers_array as $key => $value ) {
            $header_string .= $key.': '.$value . constant('END_LINE');
        }
    }
    return ( @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $header_string ) );
}
if (
    !defined('CPANEL_DOMAIN') ||
    !defined('CPANEL_PATH') ||
    !defined('CPANEL_PATH_USERS') ||
    !defined('EML_SENDER') ||
    !defined('EML_XMAILER') ||
    !defined('FLAG_DEBUG') ||
    !defined('FLAG_DEBUG_RAW') ||
    !defined('NOTIFY_EMAIL') ||
    !defined('END_LINE') ||
    constant('NOTIFY_EMAIL') == constant('EML_SENDER')
) {
    exit(1);
}
$debugging = array();
$flag_headers = 1;
$flag_plaintext = 1;
$flag_multi_plaintext = 0;
$flag_multi_plaintext_done = 0;
$headers_incoming = array(
    'To' => '',
    'From' => '',
    'Reply-To' => '',
    'Subject' => '',
    'Cc' => ''
);
$mime_boundary = '';
$plaintext = '';
debugging('searching for users');
$users = array();
$quota_users = @file( constant('CPANEL_PATH_USERS') );
if ( $quota_users && is_array($quota_users) && count($quota_users) ) {
    foreach ( $quota_users as $quota_user ) {
        $user = strtok($quota_user,':') . '@' . constant('CPANEL_DOMAIN');
        debugging('searching for users: +user "'.$user.'"');
        $users[] = $user;
    }
} else {
    debugging('searching for users: ERROR - check CPANEL_PATH_USERS "'.constant('CPANEL_PATH_USERS').'"', true);
    exit(1);
}
debugging('searching for users done: ' . count($users) . ' users');
debugging('header processing begins');
$line_count = 0;
$line_last = '';
while( $line = fgets(STDIN) ) {
    if ( $line_count >= 5000 ) break;
    $line = trim($line);
    if ( $flag_headers ) {
        foreach ( $headers_incoming as $target => $set ) {
            if ( !$set ) {
                $found = scan_headers( $line, $target );
                if ( $found ) {
                    $headers_incoming[$target] = $found;
                    debugging('headers: set '.$target.': "'.$found.'"');
                }
            }
        }
        if ( strpos($line, 'boundary=') ) {
            $flag_plaintext = false;
            debugging('headers: multipart message detected');
        }
        if ( strlen($line) <= 3 ) {
            $flag_headers = false;
            debugging('header processing ends');
        }
    } else if ( $flag_plaintext ) {
        // (default) plain text message
        //           everything after headers will be relayed
        debugging('plaintext: +line "'.$line.'"');
        $plaintext .= $line . constant('END_LINE');
    } else if ( $flag_multi_plaintext ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/^' . $mime_boundary . '/', $line ) ) {
            debugging('multipart/text: reached boundary "'.$mime_boundary.'"');
            $flag_multi_plaintext = false;
            $flag_multi_plaintext_done = true;
        } else {
            debugging('multipart/text: +line "'.$line.'"');
            $plaintext .= $line . constant('END_LINE');
        }
    } else if ( !$flag_multi_plaintext_done ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/^Content-Type: text\/plain/', $line ) ) {
            $mime_boundary = $line_last;
            debugging('multipart/text: matched "Content-Type: text/plain" header');
            $flag_multi_plaintext = true;
        }
    }
    if ( constant('FLAG_DEBUG_RAW') ) debugging( 'raw message: +line "' . $line . '"' );
    $line_last = $line;
    $line_count++;
}
if (
    $headers_incoming['To'] != constant('EML_SENDER') ||
    $headers_incoming['From'] == constant('EML_SENDER')
) {
    debugging( 'skipped resending to avoid loop - To: "'.$headers_incoming['To'].'" / From: "'.$headers_incoming['From'].'"', constant('FLAG_DEBUG') );
    exit(0);
}
debugging('resending begins');
if ( strlen($plaintext) ) {
    $reply_recipient = ($headers_incoming['Reply-To']) ? $headers_incoming['Reply-To'] : $headers_incoming['From'];

    $subject = $headers_incoming['Subject'];
    $subject = (defined('EML_SUBJECT_PREPEND')) ? constant('EML_SUBJECT_PREPEND') . $subject : $subject;
    $subject = (defined('EML_SUBJECT_APPEND')) ? $subject . constant('EML_SUBJECT_APPEND') : $subject;
    $users_bcc = '';
    foreach ( $users as $user_email ) {
        debugging('resending: +email bcc: "'.$user_email.'"');
        $users_bcc .= ($users_bcc) ? ',' . $user_email : $user_email;
    }
    $outgoing_headers = array(
        'From' => constant('EML_SENDER'),
        'Cc' => constant('EML_SENDER'),
        'Bcc' => $users_bcc,
        'Reply-To' => $reply_recipient,
        'X-Mailer' => constant('EML_XMAILER')
    );
    if ( send_mail( constant('NOTIFY_EMAIL'), $subject, $plaintext, $outgoing_headers ) ) {
        debugging( 'resending ends - success', constant('FLAG_DEBUG') );
    } else {
        debugging('resending: failed sending to "'.$users_bcc.'"', constant('FLAG_DEBUG') );
        exit(1);
    }
} else {
    debugging( 'error: nothing to relay', true );
    exit(1);
}
exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you you are heading the right direction but this is the problem I am trying to solve, I have this set so when sender@example.com sends me and email, the from is sender@example.com with CC to everyone@example.com, I want it to be only from everyone@example.com and I want to be able to modify the title to (everyone) + the original title. Is this clear?? thank you very much!

Comment: @Trufa - OK - and I'm seeing that now cPanel won't **allow** multiple addresses for forwarding... let me see what I can script up :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wouldnt know really where to start. I editing the title before forwarding any easier? I mean add (everyone) at the beginning of the title? I appreciate the effort!